# Print pdf to onenote doesn't finish, no error displays

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I'm trying to print an 18 page pdf from Adobe Reader XI Version 11.0.13.17 to OneNote 2013 on a Win7 x64 machine.

I see it Flattening, flattening, flattening everytually  message about 100% flashes on the screen then it goes away.  I believe that next I should be prompted for where save my pdf in OneNote.  I don't see that and I've looked around within OneNote and I don't see it anywhere.

I've looked in the Event Viewer and I don't see any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went in the Control Panel, chose Office Project Professional 2013, chose Change, and Repair.  During the repair process I got a warning that I was low on disk space (300 free or so Meg on a 220 Gig drive), so I freed up some disk space.  After I was done the print to OneNote worked again, so one of those two things apparently fixed it.  I'd done multiple reboots before and that didn't fix it.